# One of the rewrite rules stopped working after switching hosting providers

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ photo?p=$1
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index?page=$1  // up to this point included works fine
RewriteRule ^waitingroom/page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ waitingroom?page=$1 //doesnt work, 500 error
```

photo, index and waitingroom are actually all php files like photo.php,index.php,waitingroom.php

It works beside the last rewrite rule which is identical to the one before that :(
And it worked fine before i switched to hostgator

Whats wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Can you put `exit("here");` in whatever is supposed handle a request like `waitingroom/page/X`?

Comment: Could it be because your old host would auto-redirect `waitingroom` to `waitingroom.php` whereas your new one doesn't? What happens if you change `waitingroom?page=$1` to `waitingroom.php?page=$1`?

Comment: ive added .php to it, but no difference at all, still works for the first rewrite but not for waitingroom. I dont understand where should I add exit('here');

Comment: You are probably generating an error in your logs... might shed some light on things.